Issues with the “Question Wizard”
I’ve started a new question on StackOverflow and the wizard form was shown for me.(I never saw it before)
I’ve noticed 3 issues.

When I used code icon to format block on code, it added single back-tick instead of triple back-ticks, which made all indentation and new lines inside of the block lost.
The wizard show edit text boxes, but does not shows view of actual formatting below(as normal editing form does) It  makes much harder to understand, how the html question will look like)
When I was on the last Preview page of the Wizard, I couldn’t see the submit button, but only cancel. I am not sure, what was the reason and is it reproducible, but I haven’t seen any warnings/hints explaining what to do. Fortunately I’ve noticed that I can uncheck Wizard, which made the issues away.


I see that someone suggested to close my question, but I couldn’t see a reason why. Is it a known behaviour?

The reason selected was "Relates to only one specific network site" - the wizard is only available on Stack Overflow, so this question should be on Meta Stack Overflow. The site we're currently on is Meta Stack Exchange, for issues which affect multiple sites in the network.

@bobble Only issue #3 is specific to the Question Wizard, which is SO only. #1 and #2 are the Stacks Editor, which is a network-wide issue. Overall, this question should be broken into three different questions, one for each reported issue.

@Makyen your statement on the MSO question, that I said the Stacks Editor was SO-specific, is false. I never said that. I said the wizard was SO-specific, in response to the OP asking why they had a close vote, in an attempt to be helpful.

Many of us, including myself, don't know whether an issue has to do with the Stacks Editor as a whole and since this question only technically reports them for the SO question wizard, just see that and think the question is specific to SO only. A way to avoid this is to enable the Stacks Editor on other sites and see if the same issue applies on them, before reporting.

@bobble Yep, you're right. I generalized too much and didn't stick to the specifics. I should have been more specific that your comment only applied to a portion of this question (i.e., issue #3).
